How I can consume api in my wasm module (Kotlin Multiplatform)
I have the following problem:
I need to consume a REST API in my project, but I can’t do it in the WebAssembly (WASM) module. I’ve been trying with the following code:
suspend fun fetchApiData(url: String): String {
    println("Fetching data from $url")
    val response: Response = window.fetch(url).await()
    if (response.ok) {
        println("Getting data")
        val data: String = response.text().await()
        return data
    } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to fetch data: ${response.statusText}")
    }
}

The problem is that response.text() could be response.json() because the API returns a JSON. However, in both cases, I encounter the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: illegal cast

I had the same problem so I used response.text and then parsed it to a json. I’m not sure why but when I tried with
val response: Response = window.fetch(url).await()

it didn’t work for me, I had to write this
    window.fetch(url).then { response ->
        if (response.ok) {
            response.text().then { json ->
                val jsonString = "$json"
                val jsonResponse: JsonElement = Json.parseToJsonElement(jsonString)
                val list: MutableList<MyCustomObject> = mutableListOf()
                jsonResponse.jsonObject["results"]?.jsonArray?.map { myCustomObject -> // "results" is key in json response and it is an Array
                    val name: String = myCustomObject.jsonObject["name"].toString()
                    val id = myCustomObject.jsonObject["id"].toString()
                    list.add(MyCustomObject(id, name))
                }
                onDone(list.joinToString { it.name })
                null
            }
        } else {
            onDone("${response.status}")
        }
        null
    }.catch {
        onDone("")
        null
    }


finally I call my high order function onDone: (String) -> Unit to return it to the UI and update it
I found the kotlin-wasm-browser-template a bit tricky because they use a external interface to parse the JS-Object into a Kotlin Object, so MyCustomObject is a simple data class
